# How can I pass relationship data to a mailable in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Using backpack for laravel (love it).

So, I have this piece of code every time an user stores data (**FinanceCrudController**):

```
    $finance = $request->all();
    if ($request->input('shouldPay') == 'Yes') {
        Mail::to($request->user())->send(new NewBill($finance));
        return parent::storeCrud();
    } 
    else {
        return parent::storeCrud();
    }
```

And this is what my Mailable (**NewBill**) looks like:

```
class NewBill extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;


    /**
     * The finance instance.
     *
     * @var Finance
     */
    public $finance;


    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($finance)
    {
        //
        $this->finance = $finance;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
    *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.newbill');
    }
}
```

I can then pass the data from finance table by calling it out in **newbill.blade.php** like so:

```
{{ $finance['name'] }}
```

However, what I can't quite figure out is how to grab the relational data.

I'm using a Category table to handle categories. So, if I call the category on my blade view:

```
{{ $finance['category_id'] }}
```

I'm only gonna get the ID number for the field on the Category table.

How can I produce the actual category name on the email instead of the id of the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any public property defined on your mailable class will automatically be made available to the view. So, you could do something like this:

```
public $finance;
public $category;

public function __construct($finance)
{
    $this->finance = $finance;
}

public function build()
{
    $this->category = \App\Category::where('id', $this->finance['category_id'])->first();
    return $this->view('emails.newbill');
}
```

And then access to the category name with `$category->name` in the view.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#view-data

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the hand!